# Removing a list entry in a list in pyMongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a database collection that has objects like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("something"),
    "name_lower": "total",
    "name": "Total",
    "mounts": [
        [
            "mount1",
            "instance1"
        ],
        [
            "mount2",
            "instance1"
        ],
        [
            "mount1",
            "instance2"
        ],
        [
            "mount2",
            "instance2"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Say I want to remove every mount that has the instance instance2, How would I go about doing that? I have been searching for quite a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on @varman answer but more pythonic and efficient.

The first stage should be a `$match` condition to filter out documents that don't need to be updated.

Since the `mounts` key consists of a nested array, we have to `$unwind` it, so that we can remove array elements that need to be removed.

We have to apply the `$match` condition again to filter out the element that has to be removed.

Finally, we have to `$group` the pipeline by `_id` key, so that the documents which got `$unwind` in the previous stage will be groupped into a single document.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


client = MongoClient("<URI-String>")
col = client["<DB-Name"]["<Collection-Name>"]


count = 0
for cursor in col.aggregate([
{
        "$match": {
            "mounts": {"$ne": "instance2"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$mounts"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "mounts": {"$ne": "instance2"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "newMounts": {
                "$push": "$mounts"
            }
        }
    },
]):
    # print(cursor)
    col.update_one({
        "_id": cursor["_id"]
    }, {
        "$set": {
            "mounts": cursor["newMounts"]
        }
    })

    count += 1
    print("\r", count, end="")

print("\n\nDone!!!")
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I've implemented this and it works great. But could you maybe explain what aggregate does for others that come by this question?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Added explanation for the same

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
[
  {
    $unwind: "$mounts"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "mounts": {
        $ne: "instance2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      mounts: {
        $push: "$mounts"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8mCXmxkd611)